# Excel VBA use localized RC formula for Conditional Formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I'm using polish Excel so "R[-2]C" is "W[-2]C".

In every place I tried VBA only accepted RC notation. Which is good since it will work regardless of language version of Excel.

But for conditional formatting only "W[-2]C" works.

- **Q: Will "W[-2]C" notation work in non-polish version of Excel?**
- **Q: What alternative is there for it?**

Edit:

Here is the code that works for MY language version:

```
.FormatConditions.Delete
.FormatConditions.add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=WK[-2]-WK[-1]<WK"
With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `Offset` property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: this isn't a good question for here because it's not about programming defined in the help-center. You should ask this on SuperUser.com

Comment: @mehow Could You expand?

Comment: @GôTô, meaning I should ditch RC notation here and go for Offset + A1?

Comment: @przemo_li sorry, expand what? lol,  See the tag wiki for [conditional-formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/conditional-formatting/info)

Comment: I'd rather go with numbers, so with `Worksheet.Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber)` and the `Offset(rowNumber, columnNumber)` (if needed) to avoid bad surprises

Comment: @GôTô How can I put that in ".FormatConditions.add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=WK[-2]-WK[-1]<WK"" ?

Comment: @mehow But I do it via VBA. Maybe I was to implicit about it, but thats what I have trouble with. VBA happily accept "RC" everywhere, but for conditional formating, where I must pass localized arguments "WK" to get it working, which wont work if somebody use non-polish Excel.

Comment: You can use `Address` http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/address-HP005208983.aspx

Comment: Forluma1:="=" & .Offset(0, -2).Address & " - " & .Offset(0, -1).Address & " < " & .Address  --- Do not work :| Application defined error. Though it give nice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Language independent Excel formulae for use in conditional formatting or validation rules**

Write your formula with english function names, with either A1- or R1C1-references. Assign this formula as the *cell* formula to an appropriate cell. This could be the cell you are about to format, or any unused cell. Then read the FormulaLocal from that cell - this is the formula you are going to use for formatting. Set the formula of the cell you used as translator to blank.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Anonymous Type's answer, here's an actual implementation which you can use as a utility:

```
' Rewrites the given formula from English to the current locale.
' This can be useful when working with conditional formatting expressions,
' where Excel only accepts localized formulas for some reason.

' For this function to work, you must supply a cell which can be used for
' generating the formula. This cell will be cleared after the operation, so
' avoid cells which contain any meaningful data - use a temporary sheet if
' you already have one.
Public Function ConvertToLocalizedFormula(formulaToConvert As String, _
                                          notationToUse As XlReferenceStyle, _
                                          ByRef tempCell As Range _
                                          ) As String


    If notationToUse = xlR1C1 Then
        tempCell.FormulaR1C1 = formulaToConvert
        ConvertToLocalizedFormula = tempCell.FormulaR1C1Local
    Else
        tempCell.formula = formulaToConvert
        ConvertToLocalizedFormula = tempCell.FormulaLocal
    End If
    tempCell.Clear
End Function
```

As an example, using this with the Hungarian locale in Immediate gives the following:

```
Debug.Print ConvertToLocalizedFormula("=SUM($H5:$AE24)", xlA1, ActiveSheet.Range("AJ1"))
=SZUM($H5:$AE24)

Debug.Print ConvertToLocalizedFormula("=SUM(R5C7:R5C9)", xlR1C1, ActiveSheet.Range("AJ1"))
=SZUM(S5O7:S5O9)
```