# Formula1 in condtional formatting only accepts local formula delimiter. Is this a bug?

Tags: vba, excel

The following row works:

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
    Formula1:="=AND(R" & lHeadersAndDatesRow & "C>=RC" & lStartDateCol & _
        ";R" & lHeadersAndDatesRow & "C<=RC" & lStartAdsDateCol & ")"
```

Notice that the delimiter is `;` and not `,`. If I try to use `,` then I get an error.

The following thread reports a similar problem:
[Excel VBA use localized RC formula for Conditional Formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649293/excel-vba-use-localized-rc-formula-for-conditional-formatting)

I must ask: Is this a bug? Does it only happen in ConditionalFormating.Formula1 or does it happen in other cases as well?

Comment: Are you using the English localization or some other?

Comment: I get Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument. I have Swedish as editing language in Excel and English as display and help langauge.