# Excel VBA - problems with different locale settings

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have Excel VBA code at my computer at home that says:

```
With TableBody
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=MOD(ROW();2)=0"
```

But when I bring that code to a computer with locale settings in German (which is where the code should run) the debugger stops on that row. If I change it to:

```
With TableBody
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=REST(ZEILE();2)=0"
```

Why is that so?
I thought formulas need no translation in VBA.
What can I do about it, apart from making provisions in the code for German version?

Comment: The FormatConditions collection is about the only place this problem exists. The simplest way is usually to put the `Formula` in a cell, then read back the `FormulaLocal` property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649293/excel-vba-use-localized-rc-formula-for-conditional-formatting