# Wanting to maintain the ctrl-z function in Excel when applying modification in VBA, highlighting row/column feature

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to ctrl-z my Excel worksheet even when I have the VBA modified code in it. This code is meant to highlight the column and row of the selected cell (desired to keep track of ID numbers/other info in the worksheet when adding new information). The picture shows the results of said code).
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0w8G.png)

This totally eliminates the ctrl-z function in Excel, which could be problematic if the worksheet is not saved after every modification.

The code is below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

  'Clear the color of all cells
  Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
  With Target
    'Highlight row and column of the selected cell
    .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    .EntireColumn.Interior.ColorIndex = 24
  End With
    
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have tried a few things that will temporarily restore the ctrl-z function. This is until I *enter* or *tab* into a new which totally defeats the purpose of the function.
I want full restoration of the ctrl-z and to maintain this VBA code (or something similar).

Thanks yall!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building Undo Into an Excel VBA Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339228/building-undo-into-an-excel-vba-macro).  Although probably not the answer you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting.

To set up a range for row/column highlighting:

```
Sub SetUpRowColumnHilites()
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:O30") 'for example
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ROW()=CELL(""row"")")
            .StopIfTrue = False
            .Interior.COLOR = RGB(220, 200, 200)
        End With
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=COLUMN()=CELL(""col"")")
            .Interior.COLOR = RGB(200, 250, 200)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The worksheet event handler just calculates the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then Me.Calculate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This approach preserves the Undo buffer.

Comment: Two comments: 1) If you use non-English version of Excel, formulas in format conditions should be in local language. 2) Calculating of the entire sheet on each selection change may slow down your sheet. It is enough to use `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` or even `Me.Range("A1").Formula = Me.Range("A1").Formula`. ScreenUpdating sometimes causes the screen to flicker.

Comment: Suggestion for formula translation if required - this could be incorporated into the code I posted.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25680843/478884